# No PolyData from PolyDataReader VTK

Tags: python, polygon, vtk

I am trying to decimate polygonal data from a .vtk file but I am not getting any data from the PolyDataReader, my code looks like:

```
vtk_file_name = "data.vtk"    
vtk_reader = vtk.vtkPolyDataReader()
vtk_reader.SetFileName(vtk_file_name)
vtk_reader.Update()
polyData = vtk_reader.GetOutput()

decimate = vtk.vtkDecimatePro()
decimate.SetInputData(polyData)
decimate.SetTargetReduction(0.1) #10% reduction
decimate.Update()
```

While doing this, I get the error message "vtkDecimatePro (0x1007645b0): No data to decimate!". While trying to print the polyData object, it seems to be empty. How can I get the corresponding data?

I am using VTK 6.3 with the Python wrapper installed from Anaconda

Comment: I just tried your code with an `.stl` file and it worked fine. Are you sure that your `.vtk` file can produce `vtkPolyData`? If not, you have to read the file in the format that it has (Structured Points or whatever) and convert it to `vtkPolyData`.

Comment: Yes, I have another script that exports the data to a .obj file using the PolyDataReader and it works fine. Also, when opening the file in a text editor the 4th line says "DATASET POLYDATA"

Comment: You say "While trying to print the polyData object, it seems to be empty." Does this mean that `polyData == None` or that `polyData` has no points and no cells?

Comment: Yes, it has no points and no cells but the object is not none